# How to neatly combine a part of a list when printing in python

Tags: python

```
name = "Joe Van Schmo"
rname = name.split()
print ('{}, {}'.format(rname[-1],rname[0:-1]))
```

Ideally I want the return to be (All but the first word), (first word) but I'm not sure how to go about combining the Van and the Schmo in the quickest way.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Desired output? Consider learning what is a [mcve].

Comment: `rname[-1]` is not the first word, it's the last word. Likewise, `rname[0:-1]` is all but the last word.

Comment: Are you looking for "Van Schmo, Joe" as the output?

Comment: @coldspeed that's correct

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `maxsplit` parameter for [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
name = "Joe Van Schmo"
fname, rname = name.split(None, 1)
print ('{}, {}'.format(rname, fname))
```

This outputs:

```
Van Schmo, Joe
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a [`maxsplit` parameter to `str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), or if you know you'll have exactly one space between first name and the rest of the name, [`str.partition` implies at most one split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition).

```
name = "Joe Van Schmo"
# Raises exception if no spaces in name
firstname, restname = name.split(maxsplit=1)  # Equivalently, name.split(None, 1)

# Or without exceptions, but with possibly odd output for spaceless names
firstname, sep, restname = name.partition(' ')

print ('{}, {}'.format(restname, firstname))
```

Comment: @blhsing: Where did the OP say that?

Comment: My apologies. I mixed it up with another question.

Answer (score 0):

First word:

```
rname[0]
```

All but first word:

```
rname[1:]
```

If you want to merge it with spaces:

```
' '.join(rname[1:])
```

So your last line of code should've been:

```
print ('{}, {}'.format(' '.join(rname[1:]),rname[0]))
```

Answer (score -1):

You also can slice the `.split()` directly in your print statement

```
print('{}, {}'.format(' '.join(name.split()[1:]), name.split()[0]))
```

> ```
> Van Schmo, Joe
> ```